# Validating Vehicle Numbers of Indian Vehicle number with Jquery Validation

Tags: php, jquery, regex, validation

I want to validate an Indian vehicle number in jquery validator plugin https://jqueryvalidation.org/ in my PHP application.

How can I add additional method with `regex` to validate these number formats?

`[AA]-[00|0]-[BB|B]-[0000|000|00|0]` Ex: `DL-01-X-1234`, `DL-01-XL-123` // These are new vehicle number format

**OR**

`[AAA]-[0000|000|00|0]` Ex: `CNX-1234`,`CNX-123` // This is old number format

I want to validate both formats in the same `additional method`.

What I did till now is

```
(?:([A-Z]{2,3})-(?:[0-9]{4})-(?:[A-Z]{1,2})-(?:[0-9]{1,4}))
```

This validates only `[AA]-[00|0]-[BB|B]-[0000|000|00|0]` **bot not** `[AAA]-[0000|000|00|0]`

This question may asked by others previously, but mine is quite different I think :)

Answer (score 2):

How about this regex:

`([A-Z]{2,3})-(\d{2,4})|([A-Z]{2,3})-\d{2}-[A-Z]{1,2}-\d{1,4}`

```
`([A-Z]{2,3})-(\d{2,4})` matches second type of numbers as mentioned in OP
`([A-Z]{2,3})-\d{2}-[A-Z]{1,2}-\d{1,4}` matches second type of numbers as mentioned in OP
```

**DEMO**: https://regex101.com/r/DE1zmf/2

**EDIT**

With your comment, I realized that the regex can be simplified to `^[A-Za-z]{2,3}(-\d{2}(-[A-Za-z]{1,2})?)?-\d{3,4}$` this matches all your 3 conditions

**DEMO** : https://regex101.com/r/DE1zmf/8

Comment: Thank you. Added validation for `DL-01-1234` also with this `((([A-Za-z]){3}-\d{1,4})|([A-Za-z]{2}-\d{2}-[A-Za-z]{1,2}-\d{1,4})|([A-Za-z]{2}-\d{2}-\d{1,4}))`

Comment: Thanks for your simplified regex. 
One issue with this new regex is `DL-01` also returns `valid` as this is not a valid vehicle number. It should be like `DLL-01` or `DL-01-122` or `DL-01-D-123` etc.,

Comment: Still `DL-01` returns valid which is not

Comment: @ABCatella go with `^[A-Za-z]{2,3}(-\d{2}(-[A-Za-z]{1,2})?)?-\d{2,4}$`